# Calling c++ functions from a lib file

Tags: c++, .lib

I've got a C++ 3rd party library file with no header file.

How can I read the functions and use them inside my C++ application.

Inside the lib file are mangled names.. I used dependency walker to view the export functions.

How do I go about using these mangled names?

Create a C++ wrapper that calls these functions in C?

Could you post a example please.

Answer (score 4):

> I've got a C++ 3rd party library file with no header file.

If you got no header files and no documentation you cannot do anything reliable with that library, because it expects some *conventions* (e.g. about order of calls, initializations, who is responsible to free some data and how, invariants expected by library functions....) that you cannot guess.

Comment: i know most of the functions inside the library file as i came from a .dll.. This .dll i had working base on a hacked method i used. How would i go about being able to use the library then?

Comment: you post a example how to do it?